# How to render a Report Viewer in a MVC application seamless?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I'm currently working on a project that involves implementing ssrs reports into a web application. I followed the multiple tutorials about it and finally got it. But I can't find any information about how to make the webform rendered seamless as opposed to my screenshot.([Screenshot of a ReportViewer control inside a mvc application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzVLL.png)) Is there a way ?

---

Project configuration :

- Added the ReportViewerForMVC nugget package

---

HomeController.cs :

public virtual ActionResult Index()

```
    {
       ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer()
            {
                ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote,
                SizeToReportContent = true,
            };
        ServerReport serverReport = viewModel.reportViewer.ServerReport;
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("ServerURL");
        serverReport.ReportPath = "ReportPath";
        ViewBag.ReportViewer = viewModel.reportViewer;
        return View();
    }
```

---

Index.cshtml

@using ReportViewerForMvc

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)

Comment: Can you please add how you implemented in code?

Comment: I cannot find ReportViewerForMvc package. Can you please share the link and steps tp install it ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright did'nt know why i didn't dig there but found how to change the parameter of the iframe:

---

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new {
frameBorder="0"
})